# Issue with SSL connection with self signed salesforce certificate in SoapUI

Tags: rest, ssl, salesforce, soapui

We are trying to make a callout from salesforce to a restful service hosted in a SOA gateway server, as a means of testing we are trying to test the service using SOAP UI first to make sure the response is proper. I have been trying to read many blogs but still not clear on how to attach a self signed certificate to a SOAPUI and making a callout to a restful service.

I tried following this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx) which was closest to what i wanted, but i again when i tried following the step of export i am facing an issue that the option of 'Personal Information Exchange' is greyed out or disabled when i try to export the self signed certificate. Can any one help in giving out some steps or instructions to attach a Self signed cert to SOAP UI for a restful service.

When i make a callout in SOAPUI without certificate i am getting below response because the server is expecting a certificate.

```
<data contentType="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" contentLength="13"><![CDATA[403 forbidden]]></data>
```